# Will I get penalized by Google for cloaking if I redirect mobile users to a sub domain?

Tags: seo, googlebot, cloaking

I have a website `https://example.com` which is responsive but it came a time where it displays too much text. So I decided to create a progressive web application version and would like to deploy it lets say in `https://m.example.com`.

I would like to redirect all my mobile users to `https://m.example.com` if they access `https://example.com`. Since Google doesn't like cloaking, will I get penalized for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a mobile subdomain and redirecting users there is absolutely fine with Google.  Google maintains a [guide for setting up your mobile site](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/).  In it Google says they support three types of mobile sites:

- **Responsive web design** - One site where the content resizes itself to fit the screen
- **Dynamic serving** - One site where the server detects the device type and serves differently formatted pages
- **Separate URLs** - Different pages for mobile and desktop with redirects between them.

Google says that the "separate URLs" solution is sometimes called an "m-dot site" because a common way of implementing it is to have the mobile site on the subdomain `m.example.com`.   What you are proposing is fully supported by Google.

[Google also has a page about cloaking](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en).  Cloaking is serving different content or different redirects to visitors than to Googlebot.  It is easy to avoid cloaking with a mobile subdomain. [Googlebot crawls with both mobile and desktop](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en) variant user agents:

- Desktop: `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)`
- Mobile: `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)`

You should treat Googlebot just like any other visitor: redirect the Googlebot variant that looks like a mobile phone (`Android`) to the mobile site and redirect regular Googlebot to the desktop site.

Every page on your desktop site should redirect to the same content on the mobile site and vice-versa.  You should never redirect deep pages to the mobile home page.

When implemented properly, there is no risk of cloaking when redirecting to a mobile subdomain.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you will get penalized. [As per this page in Google's developers guide](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-first-indexing)

> If your site has separate desktop and mobile content, which means you
>   have a dynamic serving or separate URLs (or m-dot) site[...]
>
> Your mobile site should contain the same content as your desktop site.
>   If your mobile site has less content than your desktop site, you
>   should consider updating your mobile site so that its primary content
>   is equivalent with your desktop site. This includes text, images (with
>   alt-attributes), and videos – in the usual crawlable and indexable
>   formats.